# Resolução do site criado em HTML+CSS ultrapassa o 100% da tela

Tags: rolamento, resolução-de-tela

Olá, estou aprendendo realmente a trabalhar com HTML, CSS e JS e estou enfrentando um problema de resolução. Pelo menos acho que tem a ver com resolução.

O site criou uma barra de de scroll horizontal e não tem mais a resolução de 100% da tela. No entanto não faço ideia da onde isto surgiu. Pois, pelo que entendi até agora realizando os passos de programação, está tudo ok.

Segue imagens para melhor entendimento:[image: resolução 100%]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que pode levar a este erro?

```css
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Maven-Pro';
 src: url("../arqs/Fonts/MavenPro-Medium.ttf");
 font-size: 1em;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: 'Maven-Pro-Regular';
 src: url("../arqs/Fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf");
 font-size: 1em;
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 150px;
 background: rgba(94, 41, 154, .85);
 z-index: 2;
 position: relative;
}

header .container {
 color: #fff;
 width: 85%;
 position: relative;
}

header .header-black {
 background: #000;
 height: 40px;
}

header .header-black li {
 background-image: url("../arqs/Png/clubs.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 4px 12px;
}

header .header-black li.club-01 {
 background-position: 0px;
}
header .header-black li.club-02 {
 background-position: -48px;
}
header .header-black li.club-03 {
 background-position: -95px;
}
header .header-black li.club-04 {
 background-position: -140px;
}
header .header-black li.club-05 {
 background-position: -188px;
}
header .header-black li.club-06 {
 background-position: -238px;
}
header .header-black li.club-07 {
 background-position: -287px;
}
header .header-black li.club-08 {
 background-position: -334px;
}
header .header-black li.club-09 {
 background-position: -381px;
}
header .header-black li.club-10 {
 background-position: -429px;
}
header .header-black li.club-11 {
 background-position: -480px;
}
header .header-black li.club-12 {
 background-position: -529px;
}
header .header-black li.club-13 {
 background-position: -578px;
}
header .header-black li.club-14 {
 background-position: -630px;
}
header .header-black li.club-15 {
 background-position: -675px;
}
header .header-black li.club-16 {
 background-position: -720px;
}
header .header-black li.club-17 {
 background-position: -764px;
}
header .header-black li.club-18 {
 background-position: -808px;
}
header .header-black li.club-19 {
 background-position: -857px;
}
header .header-black li.club-20 {
 background-position: -904px;
}
header .header-black li.club-21 {
 background-position: -949px;
}
header .header-black li.club-22 {
 background-position: -1000px;
}

header .header-black li a {
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 display: block;
}

header #logotipo {
 position: absolute;
 top: -35px;
}

#menu {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 font-family: 'Maven-Pro'
}

.menu {
 margin: 0;
}

#menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 40px 0px 40px 50px;
}

#menu li a {
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
}

#menu li.search-input {
 width: 350px;
 margin-right: 0;
}

#menu li.search-input input {
 background-color: #512186;
 color: #fff;
 border: none;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
}

#menu li.search-input ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color: #fff;
}

#menu li.search-input button {
 background: none;
 border: none;
 position: relative;
}

#menu li.search-input button i {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
 position: absolute;
 right: -200px;
    top: -22px;
}

#banner {
 width: 100%;
 height: 1048px;
 position: relative;
 top: -280px;
 background-size: cover;
}

#txtbanner {
 font-size: 98px;
 top: -707px;
 left: 135px;
 color: #fff;
 position: relative;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .45);
 font-family: 'Maven-Pro-Regular';

}

#txtbanner small {
 font-size: 38px;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#news {
 top: -400px;
 position: relative;
}

#news h2 {
 font-family: 'Maven-Pro-Regular';
 font-size: 48px;
 color: #5e299a;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 position: relative;
}

#news hr {
 border: #fde192 solid 3px;
 width: 200px;
 top: -13px;
 position: relative;
}

#news .thumbnails {
 margin-top: 26px;
 position: relative;
}

#news .thumbnails h3 {
 font-family: 'Maven-Pro-Regular';
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #5e299a;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#news .thumbnails time {
 font-family: 'Maven-Pro-Regular';
 font-size: 15px;
 color: #b7b7b7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap-OC/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/orlando.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2d8191dca3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Orlando City</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header>
   <div class="header-black">
    <div class="container">
     <ul class="pull-right">
      <li class="club-01"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-02"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-03"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-04"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-05"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-06"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-07"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-08"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-09"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-10"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-11"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-12"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-13"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-14"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-15"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-16"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-17"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-18"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-19"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-20"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-21"><a href=""></a></li>
      <li class="club-22"><a href=""></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div><!-- Times -->
   </div>

   <div class="container"><!-- Menu e Searh -->
    <div class="row">
     <nav id="menu">
      <ul class="menu">
       <li><a href="">Tickets</a></li>
       <li><a href="">News</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Schedule</a></li>
       <li class="search-input">
        <div class="container">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
               <button class="button" type="button"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
            </span>
           </div><!-- /input-group -->
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div><!-- Menu e Searh -->
   </div>

   <div class="container">
    <img src="arqs/Png/orlando-logo.png" alt="Orlando-City-Logo" id="logotipo">
   </div>
  </header>

  <section><!--banner central + News-->
   <div>
    <img src="arqs/Png/banner.jpg" id="banner">
    <h1 id="txtbanner">Orlando City<small>Orlando City soccer club</small></h1>
   </div>

   <div id="news" class="container">

    <div class="row">
     <h2>Latest News</h2>
     <hr>
    </div>

    <div class="row thumbnails"><!--foto e título news-->
     <div class="col-md-3">

      <img src="arqs/Png/noticia-thumb.jpg" alt="Notícias">
      <h3>Orlando City acquires Goalkeeper Joe Bendik from Toronto FC</h3>
      <time>December 21, 2015</time>

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      
      <img src="arqs/Png/noticia-thumb.jpg" alt="Notícias">
      <h3>Orlando City acquires Goalkeeper Joe Bendik from Toronto FC</h3>
      <time>December 21, 2015</time>

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      
      <img src="arqs/Png/noticia-thumb.jpg" alt="Notícias">
      <h3>Orlando City acquires Goalkeeper Joe Bendik from Toronto FC</h3>
      <time>December 21, 2015</time>

     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
      
      <img src="arqs/Png/noticia-thumb.jpg" alt="Notícias">
      <h3>Orlando City acquires Goalkeeper Joe Bendik from Toronto FC</h3>
      <time>December 21, 2015</time>

     </div>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </section>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/bootstrap-OC/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Legal, vou postar o código abaixo. 
Desculpe sou novo aqui

Comment: É importante reduzir o código a um [mcve]. Mais detalhes no link fornecido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc usou `left` em um elemento que tem 100% da largura da tela. No caso no `H1` com o texto vc colocou um `left`, e é esse `left` que deu o espaço indesejado, já que por default o `H1` tem 100% da largura do `container`, ele acabou ficando com 100% + o valor de `left` que vc colocou.

Basta em `#txtbanner { left: 135px; }` vc trocar por `#txtbanner { margin-left: 135px; }` que vai resolver

Comment: Muito bom Hugo, era isso mesmo! Agora já até compreendi a diferença entre o left e o margin-left ou outras direções.  Muito obrigado!!

Comment: @Psycintra cara legal que te ajudou, se vc considera que essa resposta resolveu o problema considere marca-la como aceita clicando nesse ícone ✔  abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta, valeu a força

Answer (score 0):

A barra horizontal é um recurso automático do navegador para mostrar a tela toda.
Algum elemento do seu código está ocupando aquele espaço.
Você pode usar as opções de inspeção (Ctrl + Shift + I no Chrome). Lá você pode depurar o seu código, elemento por elemento, e verificar se é problema de width, padding, margin, ou o que quer que seja.